# BeautifulSoup - Slow down requests.get

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hope someone Have the answer.

I try to scrape a specific website.

The problem is that the requests.get(url) scrapes everything very quickly.

Therefore i'm blocked.

Is their a way to slow down requests.get(url) ?

Thank you for your help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'website.fr'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

**Print result:
As you were using this website, something about your browser or behavior made us think you might be a bot. Solve the captcha below to continue browsing the site.**

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a timeout and see if the scraper works for you.

```py
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=5)
```

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *While there is no information about url it is hard to reproduce*

A first approache could be to add some `headers` to your request - This will not slow down but adresses that there "will be browser". Alternative approache is to use selenium.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
url = 'https://www.france.fr/fr'
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(response)
```

#### Output

```
<Response [200]>
```

If you are iterating urls you also can add same delay with the `time` modul:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

...

for url in urls:
    time.sleep(3)
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to see what header is send in the origin ?

Comment: It always depends on how you interact with the page and how bot detection works on the server,... You can see the headers your browser is sending at the network tab in your developer tools